# LinkedList Methods

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I'm having trouble printing out information. The program starts out with a menu with these options:

1. Add Employee
2. Remove Employee
3. Print Employee Information
4. Exit

If you want to add an employee, it will ask how many you would like to add, but I havn't gotten to that yet.
Right now I just want to print out the employee's first and last name, and later on - in a loop for each employee.

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1. Add Employee");
        System.out.println("2. Remove Employee");
        System.out.println("3. Print Employee Information");
        System.out.println("4. Exit");


        int option = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();//for the string buffer
        System.out.println("Enter employee first name: ");

            String firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter employee last name: ");
            String lastName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter employee address: ");
            String address = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter employee city: ");
            String city = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter employee state: ");
            String state = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter employee zip: ");
            String zip = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter employee age: ");
            int age = keyboard.nextInt();

            keyboard.nextLine();
            //for the string buffer

        Employee empList = new Employee(firstName, lastName, 
                address, city, state, zip, age);


        //populate employee class
        LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();

        ll.toString();
        System.out.println(ll);

    }
```

LinkedList

```
public class LinkedList {
    private Node first = null;
    Node last;

    private class Node{
        Node next;
        Employee e;
        //Employee e;

        Node (Employee val, Node n){
             Employee emp = new Employee(val.getFName(), val.getLName(), val.getAddress(),
                     val.getCity(), val.getState(), val.getZip(), val.getAge());
             e = val;
        }

        Node(Employee val){
            this(val,null);
        }
        //SET with e, and GET from val
    }
    public LinkedList(){
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }

public void print(){
        Node ref = first;
        while (ref != null){
            System.out.print(ref.e + " ");
            ref = ref.next;
        }
    }
    public void add(Employee e){
        if(isEmpty()){
            first = new Node(e);
            last = first;
        }
        else{
            last.next = new Node(e);
            last = last.next;
        }
    }


    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Node p = first;
        while(p != null){
            strBuilder.append(p.e + "\n");
            p = p.next;
        }
        return strBuilder.toString();
    }


}
```

Comment: I'd recommend rewriting your post and providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org); you're much more likely to get responses that way.

Comment: What do you think I should take out?

Comment: Everything that isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem you're having.

Comment: Thats a shame, im really lost on this.

Comment: Which is exactly why you need to make an SSCCE. That will help, hopefully, you to understand the problem, and if not, it'll help everyone else reading your question.

Comment: Is there a reason you're declaring `Employee emp = new Employee(val.getFName(), val.getLName(), val.getAddress(),
                     val.getCity(), val.getState(), val.getZip(), val.getAge());` and never using it?

Comment: Generally with linked lists traversal is straight forward. You will usually have access to a `Head` attribute which is the start of the list. From there you can do something like `Node current = Head; while (current.next != null) { current = current.next; }` And within the `while` loop you can pretty much do whatever you'd like.

Comment: Im putting the values in the Employee class and retrieving it in the LinkedList class. Im not sure why I cant get results.

Comment: Well try debugging and see where you get stuck. I'm assuming you have `isEmpty()` function defined somewhere because it isn't shown in your code. Also, you can't really do `System.out.println(ref.e + " ")` Java will just tell you that `ref.e` is an Object. Try printing out an specific attribute of that class

Comment: As of right now, you're `Main` method won't do anything useful since you aren't adding anything to the linked list.

Comment: How do I put it in the Linked class from Employee? I'm sorry I just noticed what you mean.

Comment: Call your `add()` method. In your example you might do `ll.add(empList)`

Comment: Ooo! I got something!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107800/discussion-between-dillon-drobena-and-th30d0rab1e).